# REST API to connect a online REST server

Tags: c++, windows, rest, post, mfc

I am trying to write a REST API to connect to an online REST server. Unfortunately, I am not able to connect to the server and end up getting an error message saying "Method Not Allowed". I already tested the POST method on the online REST server using a REST API plugin from the web browser and method was accepted and the test was successful but I do not understand why my application is failing. I was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

```
    CInternetSession session(_T("MySession"));
    CHttpConnection* pServer = NULL;
    CHttpFile* pFile = NULL;
    char *szBuff = new char[500];
    CString strServerName = _T("rest.cleverreach.com");
    CString headers = _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    headers += _T("Host: rest.cleverreach.com\r\n");
    headers += _T("Method: POST\r\n");
    headers += _T("Pragma: no-cache\r\n");
    headers += _T("Keep-Alive: true\r\n");
    headers += _T("Accept-Language: en-US\r\n");
    CString szHeaders = headers;
    DWORD dwRet;
    CString strObject = _T("/v2/login.json");
    INTERNET_PORT nPort = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
    CString parameters;
    parameters = "client_id=123456&login=test@test.de&password=blahblahblah";
    try
    {
        pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(strServerName, nPort, NULL, NULL);
        pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, strObject);
        pFile->AddRequestHeaders(szHeaders);
        pFile->SendRequest(szHeaders, szHeaders.GetLength(), &parameters, parameters.GetLength());
        pFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwRet);
        pFile->Read(szBuff, 500);
        CString tempSzBuff = CString(szBuff);
        _tprintf_s(tempSzBuff);     
    }
    catch (CInternetException *e)
    {
        TCHAR sz[1024];
        e->GetErrorMessage(sz, 1024);
        _tprintf_s ((_T("ERROR!  %s\n"), sz));
        e->Delete();
    }
```

**Result :**

```
{"error":{"code":405,"message":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CString parameters;
...
pFile->SendRequest(szHeaders, szHeaders.GetLength(), &parameters, parameters.GetLength());
```

The third parameter in `SendRequest` is `LPVOID`, it expects characters usually in ASCII or UTF8 format. Don't pass the address of `&parameters`. You can use `CString::GetBuffer`

In ANSI, use

```
pFile->SendRequest(szHeaders, szHeaders.GetLength(), 
    parameters.GetBuffer(), parameters.GetLength());
parameters.ReleaseBuffer();
```

If `UNICODE` is defined, convert to UTF8

```
CStringA copy = CW2A(parameters, CP_UTF8);
pFile->SendRequest(szHeaders, szHeaders.GetLength(), 
    copy.GetBuffer(), parameters.GetLength());
copy.ReleaseBuffer();
```

`pFile` needs to be cleaned up as well.

See also [SendRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tw8chfe.aspx#chttpfile__sendrequest)

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. As you suggested I convert my parameters to UTF-8 and still got the same error message. `CStringA paramtersUTF8 = CW2A(parameters, CP_UTF8);
  pFile->SendRequest(szHeaders, szHeaders.GetLength(), paramtersUTF8.GetBuffer(), paramtersUTF8.GetLength());
  paramtersUTF8.ReleaseBuffer();`

Comment: I also converted strServerName,  szHeaders & strObject to UTF-8 but still the same error

Comment: `strServerName` and ` szHeaders` should not be converted to UTF8. It looks like your code is ANSI, in which case there shouldn't be any UTF8

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani thank you for your reply, ok even then it still doesn't fix the error.

Comment: When I try POST request from a REST API plugin on the web browser to the online rest server [cleverreach](https://rest.cleverreach.com/v2/login.json) I get the response **{"error":{"code": 400, "message": "Bad Request: `client_id` is required." }}** But when I try copying the link to the web page and paste it in the URL field on the web browser and press enter I get the same error as my application  **{"error":{"code":405,"message":"Method Not Allowed"}**. My question is whether am I on the right track using this method of for REST application.

Comment: That website is secure and you probably need OAuth authorization, in which case you are not on the right track.

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani, thank you for your update. Any suggestions as to how to change the method?

Comment: You want to set `nPort = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT` for secure websites. Earlier you said you have had success running this through a REST server, you should know if it needs OAuth or not. Ask the admin on that website. You have put `"client_id=123456&login=test@test.de&password=blahblahblah"` Did you make that up or is that based on website documentation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168820/discussion-between-sanjayan-ravi-and-barmak-shemirani).